# Gunicorn Config File I've Created Doesn't Exist

Tags: python, django, server, gunicorn

I am using Django and Gunicorn to create a blog and am wanting to run my config file that I have created.

This is the path to my config file (the conf folder is at the same level as manage.py):

`/var/www/website.co.uk/blog/DjangoBlog/Articles/conf/gunicorn_config.py`

I am in this path: `/var/www/website.co.uk/blog/DjangoBlog/Articles` and run this command:

`gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py Articles.wsgi`

However, it returns the error:

`Error: 'gunicorn_config.py' doesn't exist`

Is Gunicorn looking in the wrong place for my config file?

Any help would be massively appreciated. I have not been able to solve this for a while.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont seem to be using the correct directory for the gunicorn config file, try this

```
gunicorn -c ./conf/gunicorn_config.py Articles.wsgi
```